# find the JSONObject in JSONArray based on key-value of JSONObject

Tags: java, json, object, indexing, json-arrayagg

I have a JSONArray with JSONObjects , i want the find a JSONObject based on condition and update it . Consider my json as below

```
ManagerArr = [
{
    name : "Ram",
    employees: ["Shyam","bhavya"]
},
{
    name: "Ramya",
    employees: ["Keerthi", "suresh"]
}
```

I want to update above array when i get new list of employees, i have to find the json object by validating manager name and then add them to employees array.
i can iterate on whole jsonArray for every new employee, but do we have any in-built method to do so.
i don't want to iterate the whole array every time, can i get the index of JSONObject in JSONArray by any chance

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where did you fail?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but unfortunately, if you keep the objects representing each manager inside of an array, I don't believe you can achieve your desired outcome without looping through every manager (even if there is a built-in function that may make it seem like you're not looping, it will probably still be doing a loop under the hood).

However, if you're able to modify the data structure a bit, it can be done quite easily!

I would implement it in the following way:

```
managers = {
"Ram": {
    employees: ["Shyam", "bhavya"]
},
"Ramya": {
    employees: ["Keerthi", "suresh"]
}
}
```

If you do it this way, you can easily modify the employee information of each manager without having to loop through existing managers.

For example:

```
manager = "Ram";
newEmployees = ["John", "Steven", "Katie"]

// manager doesn't yet exist
if (!managers[manager]) {
// create new manager and their employee info
managers[manager] = { employees: newEmployees }
}
// manager already exists
else {
// get existing employees and update them
existingEmployees = managers[manager].employees;
existingEmployees = [...existingEmployees, ...newEmployees];
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this is nice , but i want it for bigger problem i simplified as this. any how i replace JSONArray with List and used the get functions of it, later converted it to JSONArray. I do agree internally it will loop